# How can i use this variable outside this function

Tags: php, variables

after calling `DemoSlideListing($apiobj,'tech',12,2)` it prints the echo portion of the function but i want to use the variable `$TotalResults` outside this function i mean anywhere on the page. how can i do this. Thanks in advance. please help

```
function DemoSlideListing($apiobj, $query, $per_page, $page) {
    $data = $apiobj->search_slides($query, $per_page, $page);
    foreach($data as $key) {
        $title = $key['TITLE'];
        $title2 = substr($title, 0, 35);
        $TotalResults = $key['TOTALRESULTS'];
        echo '<td valign="top"><div id="slide_thumb">
</div>
<div id="slide_thum_des"><strong>Views :</strong> '.$info['VIEWS'].'<br />
<a href="'.$key['DOWNLOADURL'].'">'.$title2.'....</a></div>
</td>';

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please indent your code -- more people here will take the time to assist you if your code is readable.

Comment: Strings with linebreaks should not be indented (as the indention will affect the string itself).

Comment: Do you only want the last value of `$TotalResults` ? Because this is inside a loop, you will only get the last velue of the loop, if that value is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Return it from the function.  Please review the [PHP documentation on function return values.](https://www.php.net/manual/functions.returning-values.php)

```
function DemoSlideListing($apiobj,$query,$per_page,$page){
  $data = $apiobj->search_slides($query,$per_page,$page); 

    // Declare $TotalResults as an array
    $TotalResults = array();

    foreach ($data as $key){
    $title = $key['TITLE'];
    $title2 = substr($title, 0, 35);

    // Append current value to TotalResutls
    $TotalResults[] = $key['TOTALRESULTS'];

    echo '<td valign="top"><div id="slide_thumb">
</div>
<div id="slide_thum_des"><strong>Views :</strong> '.$info['VIEWS'].'<br />
<a href="'.$key['DOWNLOADURL'].'">'.$title2.'....</a></div>
</td>';

  }

  // Return the value
  return $TotalResults;
}   

// Call as:
$totalresults = DemoSlideListing($apiobj,$query,$per_page,$page);

// $totalresults holds the array that $TotalResults held at the time the function execution completed.
print_r($totalresults);
```

Comment: $TotalResults is not printing at this time also. how to print it in footer of the page???

Comment: i am using this function at two places on the page by using different different values of the function

Comment: @rajzana Note case sensitivity of variable names. In my example above, the function is called, and result stored in `$totalresults`. That variable is available to be accessed at any point after calling. If you call the function `DemoSlideListing()` a second time, store the result into another variable, as in `$newresult = DemoSlideListing(....);`

Comment: i am explaining it more that i have used                    $totalresults = DemoSlideListing($apiobj,$query,$per_page,$page);
echo $totalresults;
                                                                       but now i want to use echo $TotalResults; below this code but it is not working. i want to do only this.

Comment: It isn't working because `$TotalResults` is not a valid variable outside the function. You must use `$totalresults` as it was returned. You can use it as many times as you need to. `echo $totalresults;echo $totalresults;echo $totalresults;`

Comment: but how to use the value of $TotalResults variable?? is there any way to do this.Please help me friend

Comment: I made a change above, storing into `$TotalResults` on each loop iteration. So the final return value holds all previous values of `$TotalResults`. You seem to have a poor understanding of how function return values work. Once you have returned your function call's value into `$totalresults`, it is available for use anywhere else in that scope.  If you need to, post more code of how you're using these values and I can try to help more.